# Passing data with Awk as a single line and avoid opening multiple sockets with pipe

Tags: linux, awk

I have a below question about parsing the data with `awk` and that works but looks not that efficient and can be improved on the point i made these.

Will appreciate any suggestion and help on this.

- Scenario one:

**Raw Data:**

```
# dmesg | awk  '/blk_update_request/{ if ($7 =="sector") print $0}' | head -5
[14740442.054675] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 3618747392
[14740442.055693] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 3618746368
[14740442.056807] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 3618745344
[14740442.057927] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 3618744320
[14740442.059074] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 3618743296
```

**Trial:**

```
# dmesg | awk  '/blk_update_request/{ if ($7 =="sector") print $6}'| cut -d, -f1|head -5
sde
sde
sde
sde
sde
```

### Note

This works well, but for simply removing semicolon `,` I'm using `cut` again which prolly adds another socket as `|`.

### Desired

Can this be adjusted with the awk itself, so as to do in a single call.

- Secario2

**raw Data:**

```
Mar 20 05:15:02 transpire kernel: [15432418.855144] EXT4-fs (dm-13): error count since last fsck: 100
Mar 20 06:16:12 transpire kernel: [15436088.797185] EXT4-fs (dm-12): error count since last fsck: 20
Mar 20 07:17:22 transpire kernel: [15439758.736285] EXT4-fs (dm-15): error count since last fsck: 40
Mar 20 07:17:22 transpire kernel: [15439758.736293] EXT4-fs (dm-14): error count since last fsck: 2
Mar 20 19:48:50 transpire kernel: [15484846.579068] EXT4-fs (dm-11): error count since last fsck: 55
Mar 20 19:48:50 transpire kernel: [15484846.580064] EXT4-fs (dm-10): error count since last fsck: 41
Mar 21 05:16:49 transpire kernel: [15518924.611572] EXT4-fs (dm-13): error count since last fsck: 100
Mar 21 06:17:59 transpire kernel: [15522594.553205] EXT4-fs (dm-12): error count since last fsck: 20
Mar 21 07:19:09 transpire kernel: [15526264.495077] EXT4-fs (dm-14): error count since last fsck: 2
Mar 21 07:19:09 transpire kernel: [15526264.495086] EXT4-fs (dm-15): error count since last fsck: 4
```

0

```
# awk '/dm/{print $8|"sort -u"}' /var/log/messages
(dm-10):
(dm-11):
(dm-12):
(dm-13):
(dm-14):
(dm-15):
error
enter code here
```

**Trial:**

```
# awk '/dm/{print $8|"sort -u"}' /var/log/messages|tr -d '():'|sed '$ d'
dm-10
dm-11
dm-12
dm-13
dm-14
dm-15
```

Again, as above i could not figured out to take this into single awk call hence i am using `tr` to chop parens and `sed` to remove `error` as that comes as a last line.

Desired: Can this be done in a same awk call?

Comment: Regarding `removing semicolon ,` - FYI `,` is a comma, not a semicolon (`;`).

Comment: The sample input you provided for scenario 2 wiill **not** produce `error` or `enter code here` in the output. If you want a script that handles such input then provide an example that includes such input.

Answer (score 1):

Where you use `dmesg | awk` for the first example and `/var/log/messages` as the input file for the second example, I will use the example data in the question and read from an example `file`

For the first part you might change the field separator to an optional comma and 1 or more spaces.

Then do the comparison with field nr 7 and print field nr 6.

```
awk -F',?[[:space:]]+' '/blk_update_request/ && $7 =="sector"{ print $6 }' file
```

If there can be more than 1 comma, you can also replace all comma's in field nr 6 and then print it.

```
awk '/blk_update_request/ && $7 =="sector"{ gsub(/,+/, "", $6); print $6 }' file
```

Output

```
sde
sde
sde
sde
sde
```

---

For the second part you could use gsub to replace the characters with an empty string, and then print field nr 8.

```
awk '{ gsub(/[():]+/, "", $8); print $8 }' file | sort -u
```

Output

```
dm-10
dm-11
dm-12
dm-13
dm-14
dm-15
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` solutions:

For your first output to get `sde` please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -F',|[[:space:]]+' '/blk_update_request/ && $(NF-1)=="sector" {print $(NF-3)}' Input_file
```

For your 2nd output to get `dm` values please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -F"[)(]" '!arr[$2]++{print $2 | "sort -n"}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use GNU `AWK` for 2nd task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
Mar 20 05:15:02 transpire kernel: [15432418.855144] EXT4-fs (dm-13): error count since last fsck: 100
Mar 20 06:16:12 transpire kernel: [15436088.797185] EXT4-fs (dm-12): error count since last fsck: 20
Mar 20 07:17:22 transpire kernel: [15439758.736285] EXT4-fs (dm-15): error count since last fsck: 40
Mar 20 07:17:22 transpire kernel: [15439758.736293] EXT4-fs (dm-14): error count since last fsck: 2
Mar 20 19:48:50 transpire kernel: [15484846.579068] EXT4-fs (dm-11): error count since last fsck: 55
Mar 20 19:48:50 transpire kernel: [15484846.580064] EXT4-fs (dm-10): error count since last fsck: 41
Mar 21 05:16:49 transpire kernel: [15518924.611572] EXT4-fs (dm-13): error count since last fsck: 100
Mar 21 06:17:59 transpire kernel: [15522594.553205] EXT4-fs (dm-12): error count since last fsck: 20
Mar 21 07:19:09 transpire kernel: [15526264.495077] EXT4-fs (dm-14): error count since last fsck: 2
Mar 21 07:19:09 transpire kernel: [15526264.495086] EXT4-fs (dm-15): error count since last fsck: 4
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc";FPAT="dm-[[:digit:]]+"}NF{arr[$1]}END{for(i in arr){print i}}' file.txt
```

output

```
dm-10
dm-11
dm-12
dm-13
dm-14
dm-15
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` to use indices as string ascending [Array traverse](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) and that field is `dm-` followed by 1 or more digits. `NF` is built-in variable denoting number of fields, when used as condition it is true if at least 1 field is present in line. In such case I do refer to key being that field of array `arr`. This does create such key in that array, note that value do not have to be given. After processing all lines I `print` all keys using `for`...`in` in order dictated by `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario 1:**

```
$ awk -F'[ ,]+' '/blk_update_request/ && ($7=="sector"){print $6}' file
sde
sde
sde
sde
sde
```

**Scenario 2:**

If you just want the unique values then:

```
$ awk -F'[()]' '!seen[$2]++{print $2}' file
dm-13
dm-12
dm-15
dm-14
dm-11
dm-10
```

but if you want them sorted then the most efficient (and portable and robust) way is:

```
$ awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}' file | sort -t'-' -u -k1,1 -k2,2n
dm-10
dm-11
dm-12
dm-13
dm-14
dm-15
```

Note that the above is sorting **numerically** on the number part so if you have strings other than `dm` and/or single or tripe digit values as well as double digit it'll all sort (presumably) correctly.

You COULD move the call to `sort` inside of the awk script but then you'd still have a pipe and would be adding awk spawning a subshell so that'd be less efficient.